# What all items does Softlayer_Hardware include

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using SoftLayer_Account::getHardware API to get list of hardware objects. I understand this gives me a list of servers for sure. Is there anything else hardware object can include? for eg: storage or any other type of object? I can see Device Type: "Gateway Member" on portal but the billing item's category code is "server" What is this object type? Can I consider this device as a server object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SoftLayer_Account::getHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware) includes `”Bare Metal Servers”` and `”Gateway Member”`.

To get only Bare Metal items (same amount of items as portal), please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[networkGatewayMemberFlag]&objectFilter={ "hardware": { "networkGatewayMemberFlag": { "operation": 0 } } }
Method: GET
```

**Where:**

`networkGatewayMemberFlag` has to be 0 for Bare metals.

Other request can help you to get the same amount of items (Bare metals) is:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
"parameters": [
"hardwareFunctionDescription:\"Server\"  networkGatewayMemberFlag:0 _objectType:SoftLayer_Hardware"
]
}
```